# Photoshop Actions: How can I add styles (fx) to layer without clearing current styles?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm trying to record a Photoshop action that applies a layer style (say drop shadow). When I run this action, all other effects gets removed and only currently applied (drop shadow) remains. How can I achieve this without removing the existing styles?

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer that will disappoint you..

It looks like there is no way to append layer styles in an action.

[**Source: Reddit - How to Automate a change to a single layer style**](https://www.reddit.com/r/photoshop/comments/3hqxxw/how_to_automate_a_change_to_a_single_layer_style/)